# View Model not getting returned on post

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc

No matter what I do in my post method the model has Answers as null.

index.cshtml

```
@using WebPortal.Classes
@using WebPortal.Models
@model WebPortal.Models.QuestionsAnswersViewModel 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "QuestionFormResponses", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

if (Model != null)
{
    string category = "";
    string column = "";

    foreach (Answer answer in Model.Answers)
    {
        if (answer.Question.QuestionCategory.Category != category)
        {
            category = answer.Question.QuestionCategory.Category;
            <h1>@category</h1>
        }

        if (answer.QuestionCategoryColumn.ColumnName != column)
        {
            column = answer.QuestionCategoryColumn.ColumnName;
            <h4>@column</h4>
        }

        Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Answers);

         <p>@answer.Question.QuestionText: </p>
         <input type="text" name="@answer.Id" value="@answer.QuestionAnswer"/>

    }
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
}
```

View Model

```
   namespace WebPortal.Models
   {
       public class QuestionsAnswersViewModel
       {
           public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        }
   }
```

Post Method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(QuestionsAnswersViewModel m)
    {
```

Answer Model

```
namespace WebPortal.Models
{
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public int QuestionFormResponseId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionFormResponse QuestionFormResponse { get; set; }
    public int QuestionCategoryColumnId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionCategoryColumn QuestionCategoryColumn { get; set; }
    public object QuestionAnswer { get; set; }

}
}
```

I place a break point in the first line of the post and go to look what is in m.  m  always has Answers be set to null.  Even though the view model is full when past to the front end, and the front end can display what's in there.

[Headers for the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TByze.png)

[Params for the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5gRl.png)

Comment: For a start, your input element is missing quotation marks for `name` and `value` attributes. Also, please include your Answer model code.

Comment: @timothyclifford added the answer model.  I'll look into the quotation marks.  I didn't think I needed them since I was using a variable, but I can look into that as well.

Comment: where's your whole action method?

Comment: Ouch -1 already.  @DanielA.White Do you mean the index method that is called before the post?

Comment: Show us the actual POST as issued by the browser.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to some of this web stuff.  Added to a picture.  Let me know if this is what you meant.  Thank you for the questions so far.  Hopefully we can figure it out.

Comment: That image is the request list. You want to use that tool to drill into the `POST Index` request (because your form's action is "index") to see its details: headers and post body. It will show you what the browser is sending and help you to determine if the application can bind to your model's property names.

Comment: @Jasen That made a little more sense.  When I picked the QuestionFormResponses post and I go to parameters I see a big list.  That makes sense because Josh was the first the result I typed in.  I also understand why they say 0 because the AnswerIds may be 0 since they weren't pulled from the db and defaulted to that.  Any idea how I bind this so it goes back to the post in the controller?

Comment: Look at the html your generating in the `Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Answers);` and you will understand why none of this works. You cannot create an input for a complex object. You need to create controls for each property of each object in the the collection

Comment: Please do not add answers in the question section. Create your own answer and remove your edit.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Changed my front end code to the following.  Front end looks terrible but now posts back

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "QuestionFormResponses", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

if (Model != null)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
    {

        <table>
            <tr><th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.Answers[i].QuestionCategoryColumn.QuestionCategory.Category)
            </th></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.Answers[i].QuestionCategoryColumn.ColumnName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a.Answers[i].Question.QuestionText)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Answers[i].QuestionAnswer)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
 }

}
```